# Anthology show question

Tags: story-identification

There was a show (in color) in either the 1970's or 1980's.  The episode I'm trying to find had a man (I seem to remember him working in a deli or butcher shop) whose father had died in WWII when his troop ship was sunk.  Somehow the son got a radio that was broadcasting as if it was WWII.  The son radios a warning to the troop ship.  The next morning, he goes to the shop and his father is there!  Somehow, his warning had gotten though and saved his father.  The son is overjoyed.  Then, outside, the morning newspaper is dropped on the corner...by someone dressed in German military uniform.  The newspaper name is something like "Cleveland Beobachter".  His father was saved, but Germany won WWII.

I've looked through episode guides of all the sci-fi anthology shows I could find, but no luck.  I'm certain it was from an anthology show, as it certainly was not from a serial.  Does anyone happen to remember what this episode and show was?

Answer (score 4):

This is likely the episode "Stay Tuned, We'll be Right Back" from the series *Darkroom*.

---

As pointed out in comments, this is very likely the same question as

[Story about a crystal radio able to pick up broadcasts from WWII; man tries to save his father/uncle](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/7112/19561)

The accepted (self) answer there reads

> It's from an anthology series in the 1980s called Darkroom. I had forgotten about this. It aired about the same time as the 1980s version of The Twilight Zone and was hosted by James Coburn. This episode was titled Stay Tuned, We'll be Right Back.